# Как сохранить состояние корзины во Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Как сохранить состояние корзины во Vuex после перезагрузки (store разбит на модули(меню, продукты, корзина))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть прекрасный плагин, называется [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate)

```
yarn add vuex-persistedstate@latest
```

Этот плагин использует `localStorage` (или `sessionStorage`, если передать параметром) браузера для сохранения текущего состояния приложения:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex, { Store } from 'vuex';
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Store({
    // ваш стейт
    state: {},
    // ваши мутации
    mutations: {},
    // ваши экшены
    actions: {},
    plugins: [createPersistedState()]
});
```

Не забываем зарегистрировать `store` в инициализации приложения:

```
import store from './path-to-store';

new Vue({
    store,
    render: (h) => h(YOUR_APP_COMPONENT)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Вкратце что делает этот плагин:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
```

Сохранение в `localStorage` происходит после каждого `commit`, а чтение после каждой загрузки страницы:

```
// source код функции `getState` из плагина

function getState(key, storage, value) {
    try {
        return (value = storage.getItem(key)) && typeof value !== 'undefined'
        ? JSON.parse(value)
        : undefined;
    } catch (err) {}

    return undefined;
}
```

Так как у вас хранилище разбито на модули, каждый модуль должен иметь локальное пространство имен:

```
const cart = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: { ... }
};

new Store({
    .....,
    modules: {
        cart
    }
});
```

Это позволяет нам избежать конфликта мутаций с одинаковым названием, коммитим мутацию через название модуля + `/` + мутация:

```
store.commit('cart/mutationName', mutationValue);
```

Comment: Описал код, который у меня с плагином - почему то не работает

Comment: @AexFun, ну во первых вынесите плагин на верхний уровень, в главный стор

Comment: Да, у меня   namespaced: true стоит, но даже когда я выносил в главный store, почему не работает, мало того, даже главная не открывается (запускаю через webpack командой npm run dev)

Comment: ага, вынес плагин в главный store и поставил в самый конец - УРА заработало) большое вам спасибо

Comment: У меня через каждый запуск npm run dev сохраняется состояние, а когда spa будет выложено на хостинг,  при каждому обращении на сервер состояние будет обнуляться или тоже сохраняться?

Comment: состояние сохраняется в `localStorage`, он привязан к домену, к серверу он не имеет отношения

Comment: @AexFun, если вас устроил ответ, то примите его (галочка слева), либо опишите что у вас не получается, чтоб я дополнил ответ

Comment: Теперь столкнулся с проблемой, что не работает функция, которая добавляет товар в массив, если его нет, а если есть, то накручивает счетчик ++. В итоге после перезагрузки страницы, товар дублируется...в vue консоли в массиве показывает два одинаковых товара

Comment: @AexFun, вы немного приумножаете вопрос и идете вперед от темы, ваш вопрос звучал `Как сохранить состояние корзины`, и как вы сказали - состояние у вас сохраняется, а то, что не работает функция - создайте новый вопрос и приведите код, и подробнее опишите что не работает

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что функция не работает после установки плагина. Плагин как будто параллельно создает новый массив. Если плагин отключить, то всё работает как надо. По сути плагин мне сломал функционал

Comment: плагин ничего не ломает, покажите код во-первых

Comment: Создал новый вопрос, как вы сказали...